# Neo4j locks CSV file even after importing

Tags: c#, asp.net, neo4j, locking, neo4jclient

**EDIT** It seems that locks (mostly/only?) stay locked when a transactional error occurs. I have to restart the database for it to work again, but it is not actively processing anything (no CPU/RAM/HDD activity).

#### Environment

I have an ASP.NET application that uses the Neo4jClient NuGet package to talk to a Neo4j database. I have *N* SimpleNode objects that need to be inserted where *N* can be anything from 100 to 50.000. There are other objects for the *M* edges that need to be inserted where *M* can be from 100 to 1.000.000.

#### Code

Inserting using normal inserts is too slow with 8.000 nodes taking about 80 seconds with the following code:

```
Client.Cypher
   .Unwind(sublist, "node")
   .Merge("(n:Node { label: node.label })")
   .OnCreate()
   .Set("n = node")
   .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Therefore I used the import CSV function with the following code:

```
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("temp.csv")))
        {
            sw.Write(SimpleNodeModel.Header + "\n");
            foreach (var simpleNodeModel in nodes)
            {
                sw.Write(simpleNodeModel.ToCSVWithoutID() + "\n");
            }
        }
        var f = new FileInfo("temp.csv");

        Client.Cypher
            .LoadCsv(new Uri("file://" + f.FullName), "csvNode", true)
            .Merge("(n:Node {label:csvNode.label, source:csvNode.source})")
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

While still slow, it is an improvement.

#### Problem

The problem is that the CSV files are locked by the neo4j client (not C# or any of my own code it seems). I would like to overwrite the temp .CSV files so the disk does not fill up, or delete them after use. This is now impossible as the process locks them and I cannot use them. This also means that running this code twice crashes the program, as it cannot write to file the second time.

The nodes are inserted and do appear normally, so it is not the case that it is still working on them. After some unknown and widely varying amount of time, files do seem to unlock.

#### Question

How can I stop the neo4j client from locking the files long after use? Why does it lock them for so long? Another question: is there a better way of doing this in C#? I am aware of the java importer but I would like my tool to stay in the asp.net environment. It must be possible to insert 8.000 simple nodes within 2 seconds in C#?

#### SimpleNode class

```
public class SimpleNodeModel
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; } = "";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"label: {label}, source: {source}, id: {id}";
    }

    public SimpleNodeModel(string label, string source)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.source = source;
    }

    public SimpleNodeModel() { }

    public static string Header => "label,source";

    public string ToCSVWithoutID()
    {
        return $"{label},{source}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure 8000 nodes takes 80 seconds? I run it and it takes 1 second. Can you share what your node looks like? Also the `SimpleNodeModel.Header` and `ToCSVWithoutID()` property/methods

Comment: I have added the class to the original question! Do you also use the Neo4jClient NuGet package?

Comment: After you said 1 second I added some extra watches and ran it like any other time and it took 1.3 seconds. What? I removed the extra watches and still, 1.3. Reverted everything I did (indexing etc) and it's 0.8. I Truly do not know what changed that it now takes 1 second while it 100% did take 80 before. I have my intermediate results still in a file and they use exactly the same watch placement.

Can you work the same magic for my edge insertion, that is even slower and has way more work to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763999/really-slow-load-speed-neo4jclient-c-sharp-loadcsv

Comment: Well - I'm glad it's back to the speed it should be! - Just in terms of the 'locking' file - I've got your code into a console app and I don't get it locking the temp.csv file no matter how many times I write it - could it be asp.net doing the locking?

Comment: I have found a new way to make sure it locks (yay..)
Client.Cypher
.LoadCsv(new Uri("file://" + f.FullName), "csvNode", true)
.Merge("(n:Node {label:csvNode.label, source:csvNode.source})")
.ExecuteWithoutResults();

File.Delete(f.FullName);

This deletes the file after (I'd say after it's completely done) importing. This crashes the program and then keeps the file locked. When manually trying to delete the file windows says "the file is open in neo4j-ce.exe", at this point asp.net is not running anymore. The file is unlocked by closing the neo4j server.

Comment: It is the server locking it, not the code (including `Neo4jClient`), if you take a `csv` file and run the cypher in the browser (`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///d:/temp.csv' AS csvNode
MERGE (n:Node {label:csvNode.label, source:csvNode.source, Id:csvNode.id})` for example) and then try to manually delete the file in windows explorer, you'll get the locked notification

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was unclear, the server locks up. It seems to keep the file locked some time after it's done inserting. If you try to access the file during this windows it seems to prolong the lock. This is indeed not your code's fault ;)