# Really slow load speed Neo4jClient C# LoadCsv

Tags: c#, performance, neo4j

The code I use now is really slow with about 20 inserts per second and uses a splitter to create multiple csv files to load. Is there a way to use "USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000" in a proper way using the Neo4jClient for dotnet?

```
    public async Task InsertEdgesByName(List<string> nodeListA, List<string> nodeListB,
        List<int> weightList, string type)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < nodeListA.Count; i += 200)
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite($"tempEdge-{type}.csv")))
            {
                sw.Write("From,To,Weight\n");
                for (var j = i; 
                    j < i + 200 & 
                    j < nodeListA.Count; 
                    j++)
                {
                    sw.Write($"{nodeListA[j]}," +
                             $"{nodeListB[j]}," +
                             $"{weightList[j]} + id:{j}" +
                             $"\n");
                }
            }
            var f = new FileInfo($"tempEdge-{type}.csv");

            await Client.Cypher
                .LoadCsv(new Uri("file://" + f.FullName), "rels", true)
                .Match("(from {label: rels.From}), (to {label: rels.To})")
                .Create($"(from)-[:{type} {{weight: rels.Weight}}]->(to);")
                .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();

            _logger.LogDebug($"{DateTime.Now}\tEdges inserted\t\tedges inserted: {i}");
        }
    }
```

To create the nodes I use

```
        await Client.Cypher
            .Create("INDEX ON :Node(label);")
            .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();

        await Client.Cypher
            .LoadCsv(new Uri("file://" + f.FullName), "csvNode", true)
            .Create("(n:Node {label:csvNode.label, source:csvNode.source})")
            .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
```

The indexing on label does not seem to change the speed of either insert statement. I have about 200.000 edges to insert, at 20 per second this would take hours. Being able to add the USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 would clean up my code but wouldn't improve performance by much.

Is there a way to speed up inserts? I know the neo4jclient is not the fastest but I would really like to stay within the asp.net environment.

#### SimpleNode class

```
public class SimpleNodeModel
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; } = "";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"label: {label}, source: {source}, id: {id}";
    }

    public SimpleNodeModel(string label, string source)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.source = source;
    }

    public SimpleNodeModel() { }

    public static string Header => "label,source";

    public string ToCSVWithoutID()
    {
        return $"{label},{source}";
    }
}
```

#### Cypher code

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV FROM 'file://F:/edge.csv' AS rels
MATCH (from {label: rels.From}), (to {label: rels.To})
CREATE (from)-[:edge {{weight: rels.Weight}}]->(to);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the slow speed of the Cypher code at the bottom, that's because you're not using labels in your MATCH, so your MATCH never uses the index to find the nodes quickly, it instead must scan every node in your database TWICE, once for `from`, and again for `to`.

Your use of `label` in the node properties is not the same as the node label. Since you created the nodes with the :Node label, please reuse this label in your match:

```
...
MATCH (from:Node {label: rels.FROM}), (to:Node {label: rels.To})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Period commit isn't supported in Neo4jClient in the version you're using.
I've just committed a change that will be published shortly (`2.0.0.7`) which you can then use:

`.LoadCsv(new Uri("file://" + f.FullName), "rels", true, periodicCommit:1000)`

which will generate the correct cypher.

It's on its way, and should be 5 mins or so depending on indexing time for nuget.

Comment: It's there now!

Comment: Yes, and it's working great! So much cleaner this way!
Would you also have an explanation for the incredibly slow rate of insertion? I'd imagine that 200.000 of these simple relations should not take more than a few minutes to complete.

Comment: I don't, I'd have to do some investigation - if you run the code directly in the browser do you have the same speed issues?

Comment: Yes, so it seems your code is, again, not at fault ;) It seems to run at about the same speed for as far as I can see. I added the cypher statement to the original question, as that seems to be the problem.

Comment: It does seem too slow